# ng-if to change class and ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<i class="tables__td--status icon icon__thumbs-up" ng-click="EventController.retrieveOne(event._id); EventController.changeStatus(event._id, event, false)"></i>
```

and

```
<i class="tables__td--status icon icon__thumbs-down" ng-click="EventController.retrieveOne(event._id); EventController.changeStatus(event._id, event, true)"></i>
```

Guys, i have this two actions in one page, one is for desactive and other to active an event.

Currently both appear in the page, i'm trying to figure out how show only one.

If event._id = true, show this:

```
<i class="tables__td--status icon icon__thumbs-up" ng-click="EventController.retrieveOne(event._id); EventController.changeStatus(event._id, event, false)"></i>
```

If is false, show:

```
<i class="tables__td--status icon icon__thumbs-down" ng-click="EventController.retrieveOne(event._id); EventController.changeStatus(event._id, event, true)"></i>
```

The problem is that i need change the class and the ng-click.

Thanks.

Comment: is my solution helps you? Do you need more details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need ng-if you can do like that:

```
<i  ng-class="{icon__thumbs-down:show,icon_thumbs-up:!show}" 
class="tables__td--status icon" 
ng-click="show=!show;EventController.retrieveOne(event._id); EventController.changeStatus(event._id, event, !show)">
</i>
```

I added to *ng-click* to change the status (show=!show), then I change the class based on the status (*ng-class*)

Comment: You used `icon_thums-up` two times instead of also using the `icon_thumbs-down`.

Comment: Sure. Thank you, Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use ngClass for changing class depends to event._id value:

```js
<i class="tables__td--status icon" ng-class="{'icon__thumbs-up':event._id === true, 'icon__thumbs-down':event._id === false}" ng-click="EventController.retrieveOne(event._id); EventController.changeStatus(event._id, event, false)"></i>
```